# How to configure my app to not list all available actions in my Users controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, routes

When I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

I get a page that says simply:

```
Unknown action

No action responded to show. 

Actions: 
create, current_user, logged_in?, login_required, 
new, and redirect_to_target_or_default
```

1. Isn't this a security risk since it tells users of my app exactly which methods are available in my `Users` controller?
2. **Why does it display the available actions and can it be configured not to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production mode you don't see any debug message like that.
Start `script/server -e production` to see.

Answer (score 1):

As earcar says, that error output is only displayed when running in development mode but that does look a little odd to me. Have you defined `current_user`, `logged_in?`, `login_required`, and `redirect_to_target_or_default` as public methods in your `UserController`? If so you'll want to move those to your `ApplicationController` and declare them as `private`, like this [AuthLogic example](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) demonstrates.

Comment: N.B. Fixed example AuthLogic example link, underscores were getting munged somewhere along the line.